# Counting column sum in sql server table

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have try to record numbers on to a db, but I can't insert column sum. Example:

Records:

```
check1      check2      check3       sum_number        roll_sum
  500         510         500           3.3               3.3(should be)
  490         500         505          -1.6               1.7 (should be)
```

But my roll sum's always is `NULL`.

My `PHP` script is

```
($sum_number + (SELECT SUM(roll_sum) FROM table_name))
```

But, if I manually put first number to `roll_sum` than script counting another rows fine.
How do I make script work fine?

Comment: Can you please share your entire query? I'm not unable to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Mureinik its above. Nothing special but u need to insert 3 values and sum_number. And script recording roll_sum automaticaly (should do). Logicaly should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(Case ROLL_SUM WHEN NULL THEN SUM_NUMBER ELSE ROLL_SUM END AS ROLL_SUM) FROM table_name
```

Comment: Yes it is NULL Because my table are empty

Comment: Because for the 1st time you try to select there is no data yet in Roll_sum, you try to select then it will give you null not 0. Then you try to add it on number + null. There is the difference. I am not sure you are using insert or update on roll_sum because your question is not detailed.

Comment: Yes this query is part of insert query. But if i try replace ($sum_number + (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(roll_sum)) FROM table_name)) not work

Answer (score 0):

use over clause

```
select * ,
SUM(sum_number) OVER (ORDER BY fieldName ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )roll_sum
from table_name
```